# Repeated use of OfflineTileProvider freezes app

Tags: osmdroid

I have an activity with a fragment which contains a MapView. The MapView uses an OfflineTileProvider, with tiles downloaded using the CacheManager. When entering and exiting the activity repeatedly, the app will sometimes freeze. Sometimes it happens after revisiting the activity once or twice, and sometimes it takes many more times(20 or more) before it freezes.

Every time I enter the activity there are two kinds of exceptions being thrown, the first one being:

```
Error loading tile
                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:677)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:145)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:134)
                                                          at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileSqlCacheProvider$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileSqlCacheProvider.java:209)
                                                          at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleProviderBase.java:297)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

and the second one:

```
Unable to store cached tile from Mapnik /0/0/0 db is null
                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                          at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.saveFile(SqlTileWriter.java:175)
                                                          at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileDownloader.java:251)
                                                          at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleProviderBase.java:297)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Have anyone else had similar issues, or know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a fun one. Looks like a lifecycle/concurrency problem. It's possible that the old instances of the map fragment are still alive. You may be able to work around the issue by forcing android to execute now:

From osmdroid test/instrumentation package

`fm.beginTransaction().replace(org.osmdroid.R.id.samples_container, basefrag, ExtraSamplesActivity.SAMPLES_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                                    .addToBackStack(ExtraSamplesActivity.SAMPLES_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
                            fm.executePendingTransactions();`

Basically, it forces the fragment transaction to happen immediately which should force the android lifecycle stuff to happen.

The other possibility is that you have a static reference to the map or something that's holding on to the map reference or your offline tile provider instance. Are any of those possible?

Edit: I just tested map in a fragment by loading and unloading the map a bunch of times and could not reproduce it. Are you programmatically creating the map or are you using xml layout?

Comment: I tried to isolate the problem by making a simple activity with only a map, but not much changed, the app still freezes. However after trying to change out the offline tile provider for another provider, the app no longer freezes. The exceptions are still thrown though.

Comment: No, im not creating the map programmatically.

Comment: it's a concurrency issue, tiles are still in the process of loading when the map is destroyed. It should just log the error message, not pause the application.

Comment: Hmmm. I will try to play around a bit with the offline tile provider and see if I can come up with a solution. I will follow up here with another comment if I find something new.

Comment: this is currently being tracked in several issues on github

Comment: @Alex osmdroid v6.0.1 was cut the other, please give that one a shot

Comment: Changing to version 6.0.1 solved the problem. Thank you!